# Creating an extension for postgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

We are creating a simple extension for postgres via Visual Studio, which crashes at building with error: 
**"unresolved external symbol _pg_detoast_datum referenced in function _foo"**

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

/* Add a prototype marked PGDLLEXPORT */
PGDLLEXPORT Datum foo(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(foo);

Datum 
foo(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text *arg = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0); // <-- error appears to be here

    PG_RETURN_INT32(1);
}
```

If we change **text *arg = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0)** to **int32 arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0)** it works fine;

Comment: pg_detoast_function is a internal PostgreSQL function (but exported). It looks like broken project configuration (missing linker option).  Please, recheck your project settings against this tutorial http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

Comment: Did you link with `postgres.lib`?

Comment: Pavel Stehule, I've used this blog to set up the project. And the project builds fine with example code from it (which uses PG_GETARG_INT32). The only difference is that I didn't found on VS 2015 "Under C/C++ -> Preprocessor Directives" settings. And yes, id did link with postgres.lib.

Comment: Guess, I've found the solution. The problem was that I was using x64 PostgreSQL version. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that VS requires x86 PostgreSQL version (not x64) to build the project.

P.S> For the future readers. Pavel Stehule's provided a link to a realy usefull tutorial for building PostgreSQL extensions in VS - http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/